# How to get unique/distinct values in included in render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like the **instituciones** values to be unique/distinct when rendering **profesionales**.
The model is as shown:

```
class Profesional < ApplicationRecord  
has_many :instituciones, through: :horarios
```

and **profesionales_controller.rb** goes:

```
render json: @profesionales.to_json(include: {   
        instituciones:  { only: [:id] }  
})
```

But I get some **instituciones** repeated. Is there a way to apply *uniq* or *distinct*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I think you might really want the JSON which would be served via an `Institucion` endpoint.

If not, then you might look to a more flexible means of generating the JSON where you can call something like `profesional.instrituciones.uniq.each`. [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) and [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) are good options for more flexible JSON templates.

Comment: I ended up using jbuilder and defined .jbuilder files for those specific controller actions where I needed them. For the rest, I stuck to [AMS] (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). Thanks!